# Xtrareport Devexpress bind data from dataset

Tags: dataset, devexpress

I have a problem with Xtrareport. I trying binding data to report from DataTable. But result is blank.

> 1. I have a documentviewer in design
> 2. Code I try to bind data

```
DataTable dt = BDMVanBanDen.SelectAll();
            var report = new rptVanBanDen();
            report.DataSource = dt;
            documentViewerReport.Report = report;
            documentViewerReport.DataBind();
```

This is my Report

[image]

and result :

[image]

So, That's why?

Answer (score 1):

In your rapport you must define the binding of your `XRTableCell` like :

```
public partial class rptVanBanDen: DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport
  {
     public rptVanBanDen(DataTable dt)
      {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        //*********you must repeat this block for each     `XRTableCell`
         XRBinding binding = new XRBinding();
         binding = new XRBinding("Text", dt,dt.Columns["NgayDen"].ColumnName);
        NgayDen.DataBindings.Add(binding); //"NgayDen" here isName of your XRTableCell
          //***********************
       }
   }
```

Now you can call your repport :

```
DataTable dt = BDMVanBanDen.SelectAll();   
   rptVanBanDenreport = new rptVanBanDen(dt);
   documentViewerReport.Report = report;
   documentViewerReport.DataBind();
```